# Updated: NLB 2 Windows Server 2003 Servers - Looking to Hire SysAdmin to solve!

Tags: windows-server-2003, load-balancing, nlb

I need to configure windows NLB on 2 dedicated servers I have.

My main machine has been running for some time, with several domain names pointing to the servers primary IP address.

Both servers have 2 NIC's installed, and both have several secondary public IP addresses available if needed?

What IP address would I use for the cluster IP, does this IP need to be added to the IP list of both public NIC's ip address list?

What IP addresses do I use for the host's dedicated IP?

Please help, this is driving me nuts...i've taken down the server twice on accident today!

**UPDATE: Looking to hire a windows SysAdmin to solve!**

I have updated my question, i would like to hire a trusted windows SysAdmin to take care of this for me, preferably today...can anyone help and provide some credentials please?

Thank you in advance!

**SOLVED!**
I managed to solve my issue myself, I was under the impression that both of my servers were on the same VLAN, but this wasn't the case. Once my datacenter sorted this out windows NLB was fairly simple to setup!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Neither of them. Long answer:

You really need to schedule all experimentation and implementation on test servers, and during scheduled/planned outage periods. This isn't something you can add to production on-the-fly.

You can approach NLB a few different ways but here's my suggestion. Allocate:

- 1 public IP address from your pool
- 1 private LAN address to each NIC
- 1 private LAN address as the cluster IP

Now, configure your public-facing router so that the public IP address you have assigned is NAT-ed back to the cluster IP you have assigned. Then configure NLB on the windows host as per the MS guide here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323431

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I beleive I am in over my head on this one...I have updated my question now and would like someone to get this job done for me if possible.